# Hide the root window when a Toplevel window is opened and make it reappear when the Toplevel is destroyed

Tags: tkinter

How can I hide the MAIN window when the SECOND window is opened and then make the MAIN window reappear when the SECOND window is closed?

I understand the use of withdraw() and deiconify() but not sure how to apply them in this situation.

The reason for this would be to eventually create a program which the MAIN window acts as a menu which hides when other windows are opened from it and reappears when these other windows are exit.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.title = "Main Window"

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Click Me", command = self.Open)
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.button2 = Button(self.master, text="Close", command = self.Close)
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


    def Open(self):
        second_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        window2 = Second(second_window)

    def Close(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class Second():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.title = "Second Window"



root = Tk()
main_window = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a binding on `<Destroy>` of the second window which will call a function that will call `deiconify` on the master.

This would be easier in your code if `Second` was a subclass of `Toplevel`. If you did that, you could hide this code inside the definition of `Second`. For example:

```
...
def Open(self):
    second_window = Second(self.master)
...

class Second(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.bind("<Destroy>", self.on_destroy)

    def on_destroy(self, event):
        if event.widget == self:
            self.master.deiconify()
```